Application.FileDialog filter for files with no extension?
I would like to alow my users to choose a file from a Application.FileDialog, but only if the file has no extension.
How can I implement that?
"*" and "*." fail with "Invalid procedure call or argument
"" is the same as *.*
Dim fp As Variant
fp = "c:\path\to\folder\"

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.Filters.Add "Extensionless files", "*.*", 1 'what do I put as the second argument?
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Select a file"
.InitialFileName = fp
    
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    fp = .SelectedItems(1)
End With


All standard dialogs are not able to search for files without extension. The single option to do that is to use Folder search option (which has such a possibility), then it is difficult to extract the filtered remained files but I think I can do it. I mean, supplying a folder path and a solution returning all files without extension (in an array) without iteration between all existing, will it be convenient?

In all Excel dialogs it is not possible to do what you need. Neither using DOS command lines. Files without extension did not have too much of a meaning when Windows has been born...
But you can do something else, instead. The folder Search facility is able to do it.
Using the next code you can open a specific folder Explorer window showing only files without extension:
Sub openSearchWindow() 'open Explorer with the search query!
  Dim folderPath As String: folderPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Text Files" 'use here your real folder to be searched for files without extension
  Dim srcString As String: srcString = "kind:=extension:=[]" 'search query for files without extension!

  Call shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:query=" & srcString & "&crumb=location:""" & folderPath & """", vbNormalFocus )
End Sub

To return the respective filtered folder files it is a little more complicated. To do that, try using the next solution:
Private Sub openSearchWindow() 'open Explorer with the search query!
  Dim folderPath As String: folderPath = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Text Files" 'use here your real folder to be searched for files without extension
  Dim srcString As String: srcString = "kind:=extension:=[]" 'query for files without extension!

  Call shell("c:\Windows\explorer.exe ""search-ms:query=" & srcString & "&crumb=location:""" & folderPath & """", vbMinimizedNoFocus)  'vbNormalFocus (vbHide not working...)
  
  Dim arrFilsNoExtension
  arrFilsNoExtension = GetFilteredFiles_(folderPath & "\")
  
  Dim El
  For Each El In arrFilsNoExtension
    Debug.Print folderPath & "\" & El
  Next El
End Sub

Private Function GetFilteredFiles_(foldPath As String) As Variant 'iterate between filtered files in a specific folder Explorer window
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") 'wait for the searched folder window to be shown. 
                                                 'You can increase the time for huge folders...
    
    'If using a reference to `Microsoft Internet Controls` (ShDocVW.dll)_____________________
    'uncomment the next 2 lines and comment the following three (without any reference part)
    'Dim ExpWin As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, CurrWin As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    'Set ExpWin = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
    '_______________________________________________________________________________________
    'Without any reference:_____________________________________
    Dim ExpWin As Object, CurrWin As Object, objshell As Object
    Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set ExpWin = objshell.Windows
    '___________________________________________________________
    
    Dim Result As Variant, oFolderItems As Object, i As Long

    Dim CurrSelFile As String
    For Each CurrWin In ExpWin
        If Not CurrWin.Document Is Nothing Then
            If Not CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem Is Nothing Then
                If Left(CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem.Path, _
                    InStrRev(CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem.Path, "\")) = foldPath Then
                
                    Set oFolderItems = CurrWin.Document.Folder.Items
                    ReDim Result(oFolderItems.count - 1) 'the last one is an empty string...
                    For i = 0 To oFolderItems.count - 1
                        On Error Resume Next
                          If err.number <> 0 Then
                             err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
                          Else
                             Result(i) = oFolderItems.Item(CLng(i)).Name
                             On Error GoTo 0
                          End If
                    Next
                    CurrWin.Quit 'close the explorer window...
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next CurrWin
     GetFilteredFiles_ = Result
End Function

The above function returns all files from a specific folder path Explorer window. So, if more windows of the same folder exists, it will cumulate the returned files!
So a good idea would be to preliminarily close all open windows of the respective folder, if any. I can also supply such a code, but I think it can be easily understand how to do it only looking to the above function code (it closes, anyhow the folder after processing its files)...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Application.FileDialog does not support a negative filter.  The best we can do is is check that the file has no extension.
Function GetExtensionLessFile(FilePath As String, Optional Title As String = "Select a file without an extension")
    Dim Result As String
    Dim FileName As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Filters.Add "Extensionless files", "*.*", 1 'what do I put as the second argument?
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = Title
        .InitialFileName = FilePath
        
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Function
        Result = .SelectedItems(1)
       
        FileName = Mid(Result, InStrRev(Result, "\") + 1)
        If InStr(FileName, ".") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Try Again", vbCritical, "File extensions are not allowed."
            GetExtensionLessFile = GetExtensionLessFile(FilePath)
        Else
            GetExtensionLessFile = Result
        End If
        
    End With
End Function

